# Django - How to get the top 10 highest scores, but limiting it to a single score per user?

Tags: django

I have a simple model to keep scores for any number of score based games:

```
class Score(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, related_name='leaderboards')
    value = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)
    uom = models.CharField('Unit of Measurement', max_length=10)

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-value']

    ...
```

My Django Rest Framework API view is as follows which is intended to get me the current leaderboard for a particular game:

```
class LeaderboardView(APIView):
    ...

    def get(self, request, pk):
        game = get_object_or_404(Game, pk=pk)

        # Get all scores order by highest to lowest
        scores = (Score.objects.select_related('user').
                  filter(game=game).
                  order_by('-value'))

        # Create and ordered dict to preserve order added
        # and only add user scores who have not been added yet
        top10 = collections.OrderedDict()
        for obj in scores:
            if obj.user.pk not in top10 and len(top10) < 10:
                top10[obj.user.pk] = obj

        # Turn ordered dict back into a QuerySet list
        results = []
        for obj in top10.itervalues():
            results.append(obj)

    serializer = ScoreSerializer(results, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

The problem is I'm having trouble figuring out **how to get the top 10 highest scores, but limiting it to a single score per user** (eg - their highest) using the ORM rather than manually getting all scores and then looping through them to ensure I only grab the highest score per user.

While my pathetic attempt to get the results I needs works, it must be very inefficient and there has to be a better way I can get these results using just the power of the ORM.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use annotation and aggregation with `Max`. Something on the line of:

```
from django.db.models.aggregates import Max

leaderboard_data = Score.objects.filter(game=game) \
                                .values('user') \
                                .annotate(max_value=Max('value')) \
                                .order_by('-max_value')
```

This roughly converts to a `GROUP BY` query with `Max` operator.

```
SELECT "user_id", MAX("value") AS "max_value" 
FROM "score"
WHERE "game_id" = 1231
GROUP BY "user_id" 
ORDER BY "max_value" DESC
```

Comment: Thanks @Saurabh! While this gets me the data technically, I can't pass the resulting queryset into the serializer as the data is flattened into just:
`{"user_id": 1, "max_value": 100}` for each result.  While I can add `user__username` and `user__avatar` and any other related fields I need to the values list, it's still flat of course and would then require another serializer to get the data into the output format I need.  While my method is a bit messy, it ended up doing what I needed without the need to create another serializer just for that.

Comment: Once you have all the users you need, you should be able to retrieve all the users detail with User.objects.filter(id__in=users_ids). Now, you can really use the serializer directly in normal sense. But you should be able to pretty easily construct a custom json response, without much trouble.

Comment: I went with the custom serializer approach and just grabbed the fields in the single query (eg- `user__username`, etc.).  However, you are correct, I could have just done a second query to get all the users.  Thanks again.